# Part identification: Board mount rotary switch

Tags: identification

I have a CPAP machine whose dial broke off. Was hoping to 3D print a replacement, but I don't see an obvious way to attach it. I figure finding the specification would help.

Has 3 leads on the bottom, 2 on the top (not visible), and one lead on each side.

There's some marking on the bottom, but I can't make them out.

Anyone know the part?

[image: Switch image with board]

[image: Closeup of markings]

Comment: does the black part in the middle turn? ... the two tabs on the sides are not leads ... they are part of the mounting bracket

Comment: @jsotola Yeah I figured they were more for structure. I can't get it to turn, but I also don't have much leverage on it since its circular. I should have gotten a top-down picture.

Comment: Looks like maybe a standard 9mm pot. If you have excellent soldering tools and skills it might be easier to remove it and get a replacement with a shaft. Can ya dig it?

Comment: please post a picture of the broken off piece

Comment: Check the ALPS catalogue. Replacement is probably about $1.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The silkscreen next to it says "SW4", so I wouldn't expect it to be a pot.

Comment: @sw4 could be a rotary encoder for sure,

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo If you could tell us the make and model of the machine, perhaps someone would be able to find the actual part number of the broken component.

Comment: @jsotola I don't have it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The broken part resembles the one on the right in this picture.

[image]

It  appears similar to this rotary encoder switch with a push switch. It's a 5 pin SMD type with three pins for the encoder and two for the push switch.

[image]

Quadrature pulses generated by the rotary encoder switch would be used for scrolling through the menu and the push switch for selecting an option, during set-up.

Comment: it is possible that the component is a `rotary pulse switch` like this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/407225/unusual-rotary-encoder-output?r=SearchResults

Comment: Yes, they are similar.